# onpopstate event is not triggered when using replaceState

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, popstate

In my application, when the user navigates to a page via the navigation bar, it loads its content inside an iframe.
The iframe is pushing a new entry to the history, and I want to reflect as well the url on my address, so I'm using `history.replaceState` to do so.
The problem is, that when I'm trying to listen to window.onpopstate, when clicking back and forward in the browser the event is not triggered.
The parent application is an angular 5 application and the child app which is inside the iframe is an angular 5 app as well.
Any idea why and how to trigger the onpopstate event in such a case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`history.replaceState` does not put a new history entry on the stack, so you won't be able to navigate to the previous state. Use `history.pushState` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since the iframe adds an entry to the history, and if I will use history.pushState then I will have to click the back button twice to go back to the previous page. Any other ideas ?